# Protractor not redirecting (finding element on next page)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

My protractor script not picking up element on next page. It runs the test on the first page **(filling in customers details)**. Upon clicking to redirect, cmd fires;

> Failed: No element found using locator: by.model("formData.card_no")

Is it because angular is not loading or must I inject `$scope`.

I'm new to protractor. Tried all sorts of `waits` and `sleeps` on the driver.. plus `ignoreSynchronisation`.. nothing.

*However when I manually place the generated ID at the end of the payment details' url,  it picks up all the elements and all tests are passed.*

So the problem must be with fetching the seller's generated transaction ID from the backend to continue with test. Not certain how it's done in Protractor.

[image: After conf.js with protractor (screen shot)]

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {
 'browserName': 'chrome'
},

pecs: ['../test/*spec.js'],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true,
  defaultTimeoutOutInterval: 30000
 }
};
```

**todo-spec.js**

```
var util = require ('util');

describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {

browser.get('https://xxx');
element(by.css('.start-btn')).click();
var seller_details = require('../page/seller_details.js');

it ('should be bla bla bla', function(){
    seller_details.enterFormName();
    seller_details.enterFormCell();
    seller_details.enterFormEmail();
    seller_details.enterFormVR();
    seller_details.enterFormVV();
    seller_details.checkFormNotStolen();
    seller_details.clickStart();

    //after redirecting to payment details page
    payment_details.enterCardNo();
    payment_details.enterCardHolder();
    payment_details.enterExpiryMonth();
    payment_details.enterExpiryYear();
    payment_details.enterCVV();
 });

});
```

**seller_details.js** (page object)

```
require ('../page/payment_details.js')

var seller_details = function(){
    this.enterFormName = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.name')).sendKeys('ron');
};

this.enterFormCell = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.cell')).sendKeys('0734555543');
};

this.enterFormEmail = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.email')).sendKeys('ron@sqw.com');
};

this.enterFormVR = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.veh_reg')).sendKeys('ND 3491');
};

this.enterFormVV = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.veh_vin')).sendKeys('13ADFPORT4QP9CR5L');
};

this.checkFormNotStolen = function(){
    element(by.model('formData.not_stolen')).isSelected();
};

this.clickStart = function(){
    element(by.css('.spinner-btn')).click();
    return require('./payment_details.js');
 };
};
module.exports = new seller_details();
```

**payment-details.js** (another page object)

```
var payment_details = function(){
this.enterCardNo = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.card_no')).sendKeys('4111111111111111');
};

this.enterCardHolder = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.card_holder')).sendKeys('yayayay');
};

this.enterExpiryMonth = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.expiry_month')).sendKeys('12');
};

this.enterExpiryYear = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.expiry_year')).sendKeys('2019');
};

this.enterCVV = function(value){
    element(by.model('formData.cvv')).sendKeys('123');
};

this.clickBtn = function(value){
    element(by.css('.spinner-btn')).click();
};
};
module.exports = new payment_details();
```

Thanks in advance for any help rendered. Let me know if you need `controller.js` which has the `$scope`.

Comment: Have you tried using [browser.wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) combined with [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions)? Something along the lines of  `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf('yourElement', 5000)).then(function () { expect(something).toBe(true); });`

Comment: @Gunderson what would my 'yourElement' be in this case? There's a `request_id` that needs to be fetched from my **controller.js** and automatically appended to the url to redirect to the next form page.. (as with usual form redirects). Protractor / Jasmine (with `expect`) needs to return that promise(`return_id`) with each transaction (different user). I think what I need here is help with pointing my **todo-spec.js** to recognize **controller.js** which is in my main app and fetch responses from `$scope`. Injection

Comment: Well your error is a `no element found` -- so my suggestion is to wait for that specific element (`by.model("formData.card_no")`) to be present before executing that `sendKeys` action

Comment: @Gunderson sounds like a good option. Tried it and it holds up for some default time before it vanishes. Returning `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: Hmmm and at the point of timeout the next page has definitely completed loading?

Comment: Next page doesn't load. After filling in info on the first page, It hangs till timeout - not redirecting to second page.. Note that everything works when I add virtually anything to the expected url of next page - numbers, letters etc. That's a lame hack obviously coz you want to maintain integrity and linkage to other forms on different pages for the same transaction

Comment: Ohh sorry, I thought you problem was a combination of redirecting and finding an element (well it is, but redirecting is the first issue)... obviously my solutions won't work if it's not redirecting.  I have no idea on injecting angular services, I'll remove some comments and we'll see if someone else has an answer.

Comment: thanks though @Gunderson

Comment: @colinDev256 how much time does it take for the payment-details page to load? I think this page takes time to load and the spec is timing out, so probably you will have to increase the timeout period in conf file

Comment: @MeanMan didn't work. Also for some strange reason, my `browser.waits` don't seem to do anything. Only the `sleep`s do work